# Alphabetized list labeling with boxed alphabets in enumeration

Tags: lists, labels, enumitem

I want to create itemized list with its labels as Alphabets, written inside boxes. I tried to use

`\begin{enumerate}[label={$\boxed {\Alph*}$}]`,

but it does not work. Pl. help.

Comment: You're line `does not work` ... is not really helpful. Apparently you use `enumitem` package and do not have `amsmath` or `mathtools` included, which is most probably the cause why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `label=...` syntax gives a clue that `enumitem` is used. `\boxed` is from `amsmath` or `mathtools` package, but it doesn't need to be enclosed with a `$...$` pair, since it's basically the same as `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\fbox{\Alph*}}]
  \item text text text
  \item text text text
  \item text text text
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\fbox{\Alph*}},resume]
  \item text text text
  \item text text text
  \item text text text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why even use `\boxed` and not just `\fbox`? Then we don't go over math

Comment: @daleif: Good point ;-) I could change, but I've the personal impression, that `\boxed` provides a better box?

Comment: `\boxed` = `\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}`. The only difference I can see is a slight difference in width of the boxes, perhaps because one is a text font and the other a math font?

Comment: @daleif: Alright, I change. Happy now? ;-)

Comment: I tried doing as instructed, but it does not work. It says: Argument of \boxframe has an extra }.

Comment: @ShalabhJain: I don't know where `\boxframe` is from

Comment: @ShalabhJain always post something that is a close to your actual problem as possible. You are basically wasting our time if your actual document is using other constructions than then ones you present. Also, always make compilable examples not sniplets

Comment: I thought 10 times and searched internet before venturing into stackexchnage. I have been here for last one year, but the rules are very strict. One has to be already intelligent enough in latex to even ask questions, which i am not. The compiler reports the error, which I reported.  I do not know from where it comes from, but the compiler says: Argument of \boxframe has an extra }.

Comment: @ShalabhJain: Which TeX version do you use?

Comment: I use TexShop V 3.23.

Comment: @ShalabhJain: That's your editor, not the TeX version! I use pdfLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015), and the `enumitem` package is of version 3.5.2 (year 2011)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thank you for the help. Since it should work as suggested by you hence I accepted your answer. There may be some issue with my version. Thanks again. :-)